# while developing my web page on visual studio code, the changes made on VSC have suddenly stopped appearing on my page

Tags: visual-studio-code

while developing a web page on Visual studio code i noticed that the changes i was making on VS has stopped appearing on my web page. everything was working fine before and even in inspect mode on my page the changes was still happening. but when i tired to copy/paste onto VS code and saved/saved all nothing is happening.

i have tried the following things.

- Refresh the page on the browser with CTRL + F5, this will refresh the browser's cache.
- Open the folder again on VS code and make sure you're opening the index.html file from the same folder in the browser

any other suggestions would be great because i am really stuck, it was working fine for most of my web page and saving all of the changes but out of nowhere just randomly stopped working all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, if I was in your situation, I would retrace what I added that made the error.

- Were you working on HTML, CSS, JS.
- Did you expand the dom and it's not in order?
- Are you links written properly?

Then If I couldn't remember, I would start to take out links and scripts to see if I can start seeing the content back on the webpage.

If I have just one script or one link, I would start copying that code to another file piece by piece until I find the error.

Similar to how as a combat engineer tests the continuity of his det cord, or an electrician finds faults in the wiring. Test portions of the code at a time, and when you find out that when you take this chunk out of the code, it's working again, slowly add the code back in until it doesn't work, and then you have sourced your issue.

You might know this already but...

For future references, because I had to learn the hard way as well, anytime you make a change refresh the website. This way you know right away what the issue is.

If it's code that applies to multiple pages, check those pages for any type of script or link unique to that page that could be effected.

Also keep multiple copies of a website. I keep mine on Github, but you can zip it and put in on any cloud service. Also keep a copy on your desktop.

This is a really good habit to build and works for me for sourcing any errors I have quickly.

I hope this helps.